# Posicionar mi localización en google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Estoy intentando posicionar mi localización en un mapa de google maps(el GPS ya está activado). Para ello tengo el siguiente código, el cual se ejecuta en el oncreate:

```
    LocationManager objLocation=null;
    LocationListener objLocListener;
    objLocation=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    objLocListener=new MiPosicion();
    if(objLocation.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    objLocation.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, objLocListener);
        if(MiPosicion.latitud>0){

            l=MiPosicion.coordenadas;
        }
    }
```

Para poder guardar obtener la localización realicé la siguiente clase:

```
public class MiPosicion implements LocationListener {
public static double latitud;
public static double longitud;
public static boolean statusGPS;
public static Location coordenadas;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitud=location.getLatitude();
    longitud=location.getLongitude();
    coordenadas=location;
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
statusGPS=true;
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
statusGPS=false;
}
}
```

El problema que tengo es que no se ejecuta el método `onLocationChange(location)` cuando se ejecuta `objLocation.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,objLocListener);` ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: he agregado una nueva respuesta, con un ejemplo para que tu mismo pruebes y asegures lo que comento en mi respuesta, saludos!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La forma de lograr que se vuelva a llamar `onLocationChange()` es cuando definimos `requestLocationUpdates()`,

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES, MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES, locListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

el segundo parámetro define el tiempo que transcurre entre cada actualización y el tercer parámetro, el mínimo cambio de distancia para cada actualización.

Por ejemplo si definimos :

```
  //Minimo tiempo para updates en metros.
    private static final long MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES = 10; // 10 metros
    //Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
    private static final long MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minuto
```

Esto quiere decir que si nos movemos 10 metros y transcurre 1 minuto, se llamara el método `onLocationChanged()` , donde podemos obtener los nuevos valores de geolocalización  provista por el proveedor.

Si no cambia la geolocalización porque no se movio el dispositivo es porque no es necesario obtener nuevos valores de Geolocalización y se usan los últimos adquiridos.

Agrego un ejemplo para que tu mismo puedas probar lo que comento:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    private LocationManager mLocMgr;
    private TextView textViewGPS;

    //Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
    private static final long MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES = 10; // 10 metros
    //Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
    private static final long MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minuto

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout rl = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        setContentView(rl);
        rl.addView(linearLayout);

        textViewGPS = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayout.addView(textViewGPS);


        mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Requiere permisos para Android 6.0
            Log.e(TAG, "No se tienen permisos necesarios!, se requieren.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 225);
            return;
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "Permisos necesarios OK!.");
            mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES, MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES, locListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
        }

    }

    public LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Lat " + location.getLatitude() + " Long " + location.getLongitude());
            textViewGPS.setText("Lat " +   location.getLatitude() + " Long " + location.getLongitude());
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled()");
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProviderEnabled()");
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onStatusChanged()");
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Si, pero eso me coge la posición al cabo de 60000 milisegundos. ¿Cómo puedo coger la posición en ese mismo instante?

Comment: Probé con lo que me indicas y sigue sin llamarme al método onLocationChanged(Location location) en ninguna de las dos ocasiones.

Comment: ya intentaste cambiar de tipo de proveedor a NETWORK_PROVIDER para obtener la localizacion mediante red?

Comment: Vale, cierto, así me funciona. Debía de ser que me faltaba algún permiso. Muchas gracias :D