# Explicación requestlocationupdates - locationManager Parametros

Tags: android, geolocalización, gps

Actualmente quiero que mi aplicación registre las coordenadas, cuando estas sean diferentes pero cada `1.5` o `2` metros de diferencia a la coordenada anterior, y si la posición no ha cambiado entonces no la registre.

Se que el método `requestlocationupdates` maneja 4 parámetros ¿dónde puedo controlar eso?, pero me gustaría una explicación mas detallada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder realizar una comparación con respecto a la coordenada anterior, debe de realizarse una lectura, el registro/almacenamiento de estos datos lo decides tu en base a la comparación.

La forma de usar el método [`requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) es la siguiente:

```
  //Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
    private static final long MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minuto
  //Minima distancia para updates en metros.
    private static final long MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES = 1.5; // 1.5 metros


locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES, MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES, locListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

el segundo parámetro define el tiempo que transcurre entre cada actualización y el tercer parámetro, el mínimo cambio de distancia para cada actualización, en este caso 1.5 metros.

Puedes ver un ejemplo **[aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8544/posicionar-mi-localizaci%C3%B3n-en-google-maps/8550#8550)**.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la respuesta, pero me gustaria saber como comparar estas posiciones ya que cada vez que se cumple el tiempo minimo, me muestra las coordenadas anteriores si el movil no esta en movimiento

Comment: Si no esta en movimiento no vuelve a requerir los datos ya que tienes configurado que tienes que moverte 1.5 metros. Por esa razón no obtienes un valor diferente.

Comment: Pero entonces como hago para capturar la posición si la nueva posición es como minimo 1.5 metros mas distante

Comment: tienes implementado el método onLocationChanged() ?

Comment: Si claro es este quien me retorna la latitud y longitud cada 4 segundos porque asi fue que lo configure                                                    //Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
    private static final long MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES = 4000; // 4 segundos
    //Minimo tiempo para updates en metros.
    private static final float MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES = 2; // 1.5 metros

Comment: Realiza una prueba, cuando te muevas más de 1.5 metros debes obtener ahí valores distintos de Lat/Lng

Comment: Obtuve los valores sin moverme, es decir estando quieto el evento onLocationChanged me retorno Log/Lat, cada 4 segundos y me dio la misma posición lo que es correcto, pero como hago para que dada esta situación yo no guarde esa coordenada, ya que es la misma y no necesitaria registrarla en base de datos

Comment: ok usa getLastKnownLocation() con eso obtienes el valor de la última lectura,    location = locationManager                           .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);   y lo puedes comprarar con la que obtienes con requestLocationUpdates().

Comment: para el cado de duplicidad, utilice unique key (fecha, lat, lon) y si es un vehículo en un minuto puede recorrer 1km sin trafico ¿ahí como actúa el 1.5 mts y el minuto de actualización?

Comment: @LuisMata En el caso que indicas si la velocidad es considerable puedes aumentar la longitud en la cual requieres una nueva geolocalización e incluso acortar el tiempo entre cada petición ya que la posición cambiaría rápidamente.

Comment: Ok esto es complejo, y esto lo puedo hacer automáticamente en una sola aplicación? en el caso de tener un vendedor de a pie y otro motorizado, ¿o serian 2 app de acuerdo a cada tipo de usuario? sino me lleno de localizaciones, estoy tratando de usar getAccuracy() pero sale que Location no contiene esa definición

Comment: o tener un panel de opciones, donde el usuario configure estas opciones según tipo de usuario, a pie o motorizado.. ummmm a escarbar..