# como puedo programar thread en mi aplicacion de android?

Tags: android-studio, hilos

como puedo programar con threads soy nuevo en android studio y no se como implementarlos debido a que al utilizar localizacon gps mi aplicacion se vuelve muy lenta, este es el codigo que utilizo para la localizacion

```
/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        MyLocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocListener.setMainActivity(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Requiere permisos para Android 6.0
            Log.e("Location", "No se tienen permisos necesarios!, se requieren.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 225);
            return;
        }else{
            Log.i("Location", "Permisos necesarios OK!.");
            mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) mlocListener);
        }
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) mlocListener);



    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_inicio, menu);
        return true;

    }


    public void setLocation(Location loc) {
        //Obtener la direccion de la calle,colonia, municipio,estado a partir de la latitud y la longitud
        if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address address = list.get(0);
                    tvdireccion .setText(address.getLocality() + "," + address.getAddressLine(0) + "," + address.getSubLocality() + ", " + address.getAdminArea() + ", " + address.getCountryName());

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
        for (ValidationError error : errors)
        {
            View view = error.getView();
            String message = error.getCollatedErrorMessage(this);

            if (view instanceof EditText) {
                ((EditText) view).setError(message);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        Ubicacion mainActivity;

        public  Ubicacion getMainActivity() {
            return mainActivity;
        }

        public void setMainActivity(Ubicacion mainActivity) {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cada vez que el GPS recibe nuevas coordenadas
            // debido a la deteccin de un cambio de ubicacion
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();

            String Text = "Latitud: " + loc.getLatitude();
            String Text2 = "Longitud: " + loc.getLongitude();
            tvlatitud.setText(Text);
            tvlongitud.setText(Text2);
            this.mainActivity.setLocation(loc);



        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            //metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es desactivado
            notificacion.setText("GPS Desactivado");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es activado
            notificacion.setText("GPS Activado");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // Este mtodo se ejecuta cada vez que se detecta un cambio en el
            // status del proveedor de localizacin (GPS)
            // Los diferentes Status son:
            // OUT_OF_SERVICE -> Si el proveedor esta fuera de servicio
            // TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE -> Tempralmente no disponible pero se
            // espera que este disponible en breve
            // AVAILABLE -> Disponible
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hay varias formas para crear un hilo de ejecución thread, todo depende del proposito, es decir si solo quieres que se ejecute un código cuando tu requieres, asyntask, que siempre se este ejecutando en segundo plano service, cada x tiempo, runnable

Comment: Tambien te podrías mirar la nueva api que ofrece google para la geolocalización no cosume tanta batería https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: Osvaldo, Lo que comenta Webserveis es muy importante debemos de cambiar a [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) , la obtención de datos es aún mas optimizada!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código no estas usando específicamente un Thread, lo que podemos observar es que estas realizando lecturas de geolocalizacion continuamente,

```
  mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) mlocListener);
```

debes configurar para no realizar continuamente esto o tu aplicación será muy lenta, este ejemplo es para configurar lecturas cada minuto y cuando te mueves una distancia mínima de 1.5 metros:

```
 //Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
    private static final long MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minuto
 //Minima distancia para updates en metros.
    private static final long MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES = 1.5; // 1.5 metros


locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES, MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES, locListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

más [información en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/25938/95).

Answer (score 0):

Create una nueva clase HiloGPS o como quieras llamarla y la extiendes `AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>` e implementas el `LocationListener`.
Lo ejecutas donde quieras.

```
public class HiloGPS extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> implements LocationListener{

//Constructor 
//metodos implementados...
//Metodo con intent para recoger los datos ,asi luego los podaras recoger donde tu quieras

}
```