# Problema al obtener ubicación del usuario

Tags: android, app, permisos

Estoy haciendo una app y quiero obtener la ubicación del usuario cuando se registra. Esto lo conseguí hace unos días, hasta pude medir distancias con las coordenadas y todo. Ahora de repente me sale un error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null
>   object reference

paso el código que tengo para ver si pueden decirme cual es el error.
En el `OnCreate` tengo esto:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Registro.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);
}else{
    geoPoint = obtenerUbicacion();
}
```

El geoPoint lo declaro antes del `OnCreate`.
Estas son las funciones:

```
public GeoPoint obtenerUbicacion() {
    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    GeoPoint geoPoint;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Registro.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);
    }
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
    geoPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    return geoPoint;

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
    if (requestCode == LOCATION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // permission was granted, yay! Do the
            // contacts-related task you need to do.
            geoPoint = obtenerUbicacion();
        } else {
            // permission denied, boo! Disable the
            // functionality that depends on this permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Registro.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.
    }
}
```

La función para obtener la ubicación la saqué de una respuesta de acá.
Solo quiero obtener la ubicación en ese momento, no quiero un listener de la ubicación.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad **lo que sucede es que no hay una lectura previa de geolocalización por esta razón, al llamar el método `getLastKnownLocation()` obtienes un valor null.**

cuando no se tiene un registro de geolocalización debes llamar el método [requestLocationUpdates()](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) para obtener una actualización o leerlo por primera vez, te sugiero también validar si location tiene valor null.

```
public GeoPoint obtenerUbicacion() {
    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    GeoPoint geoPoint;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Registro.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);
    }
     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

        if(location == null){ //Validación que evita NullPointerException
        //Requiere actualización
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener, Looper.getMainLooper());    

        //Devuelve punto en coordenadas 0,0.
          geoPoint = new GeoPoint(0,0);
        }else{
           geoPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        }
     return geoPoint;
}
```

Revisa:

[Explicación requestlocationupdates - locationManager Parametros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25928/explicaci%c3%b3n-requestlocationupdates-locationmanager-parametros)