# LocationListener no llama (Android Studio / java)

Tags: java, android

como están? tengo el problema que hay veces, muy muy raras, que el locationlistener no responde en android. Es como que nunca ingresa y mi app queda colgada porque si o si necesito enviar valores en latitud y longitud.

Les comparto el código para que me indiquen si estoy haciendo algo mal o si hay alguna manera de que si el locationlistener no responde o sea no ingreso para poder ejecutar el onLocationChanged setear los valores de latitud y longitud como nulo.  Desde ya gracias.

```
 public void GPS(final Direccion direccion) {

    intentos = 0;
    cantidad = 1;
    precision = 100;
    precisionIngresa = 100;
    tomaGPSMedidor =0; // se implementa para
    latitudHome=  "";
   longitudHome= "";
   acuracyHome="";
     providerHome= "";
    timeHome= "";

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());

    final BUILDING_TYPE building_type = db.isBuildingWithoutLectures(direccion.get_street(), direccion.get_altura());



            Log.d("Boton", "ingresa al else");
            locationListener = new LocationListener() {


                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    precisionIngresa = location.getAccuracy();

                    if (precisionIngresa < precision) {
                        precision = precisionIngresa;
                    }
                    if ( precision < presicionServer && intentos <= intentosBuilding && cantidad == 1 && building_type.equals(BUILDING_TYPE.NO_BUILDING) && String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()) != null  ) {//Busca un punto gps en cantidad de intentos determinados

                        latitudHome= (location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) : "");
                        longitudHome=(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) : "");
                        acuracyHome=(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()) : "");
                        providerHome=(location != null ? location.getProvider() : "");
                        timeHome=(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getTime()) : "");
                        cantidad = 2;
                        ubicacionEdificio = 0;


                    } 
                    if (cantidad == 2 ) {
                        if ( locationListener != null) {

                            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                        }
                        locationListener = null;
                    }
                        intentos = intentos + 1;

                }
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.d("Boton", "onStatusChanged");
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                    Log.d("Boton", " onProviderEnabled");
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                    Log.d("Boton", "onProviderDisabled");
                }
            };

            int persmissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddressScreen.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Se habilita el provider? que ves en tu logcat acerca de onProviderEnabled y onProviderDisabled

Answer (score 1):

Debes inicializar correctamente LocationManager de esta forma, si location es diferente de null puedes obtener la geolocalización.

Es importante tengas plan de datos y activada la geolocalización en tu dispositivo para usar como proveedor GPS_PROVIDER.

```
     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

 if(location == null){ //Validación que evita NullPointerException
        //Requiere actualización
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener, Looper.getMainLooper());    
  }

}
```

Te sugiero revises:

[Problema al obtener ubicación del usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285306/problema-al-obtener-ubicaci%c3%b3n-del-usuario/285377#285377)

[Explicación requestlocationupdates - locationManager Parametros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25928/explicaci%c3%b3n-requestlocationupdates-locationmanager-parametros)

Comment: Hola Jorge cómo estás?, el LocationManager lo cree en el oncreate. El tema es que tengo en dos metodos dos locationlistener = new locationlistener ya que necesito manipular el onLocationChanged de distinta manera.. Puede ser que el error este en que los dos se llaman locationlistener los dos y no con el nombre de otra variable?

Comment: Hola, si estas redefiniendo el listener eso puede ser un problema, te sugiero definir el listener en onCreate y ese listener llamarlo en >  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener, Looper.getMainLooper());